# Why would MySQL return NULL yet there is a value in the field?

Tags: mysql

I am running a join on 3 large tables (over a hundred thousand rows each). The query returns 4 rows as expected, but one of the rows has a "NULL" value, yet in the table is a value I expect to see. I am sure the value is in the db because I can see it in the table, but for some reason, MySQL is returning everything except that particular value. I am not getting any errors. The query runs exactly as expected, except for this null value. See the screenshot below:

[image]

My Question is why would this happen? Has anybody experienced this? Could it be a bug in phpmyadmin? This query is supposed to be a report of some transactions, so you can imagine how funny the report is looking with a blank field that cannot be explained!

Comment: This is not a bug in phpmyadmin; one can tell by knowing how a `LEFT JOIN` works, and more importantly what happens when it cannot find a row matching the condition in the right table (here, `tbl_accounts` where `accountId` != `transactionReceiver`). Check that condition in particular, for instance by adding a subquery `COUNT(*)` in order to identify whether that join is indeed returning 0 rows.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures. Post it as text in a code block.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld thanks for the comment and pointer. Thing is the condition is actually being met. I have found the match of `accountId and `transactionReceiver`. I expected 4 rows, and it returned 4 rows. The issue is just one of the fields in the rows.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel sorry Paul. I don't normally do that. It's just that I felt if I were to post the code, I would have to post a lot of it, creating all the tables involved, then the query and it would have been very long and hectic and boring. I thought a screenshot would provide a better overview.

Comment: it doesn't. Actually it provides a way worse overview even than posting nothing at all

Comment: Very well then. My bad. I will post the code.

Comment: @Stone10 You should provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would be three tables reduced to primary and foreign keys. You need only one row in the first table with the transactionID = 163751 and only one row in other tables which are related to that transactionID. Then you should reduce the query to select only primary and foreign keys without a WHERE clause. And while you create a MCVE - 9 of 10 times you would find your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing it with the inner join (clasic one) , when you do a left join it brings all rows from the left table and those who did not match have null values.

here they explain it better and you can see examples

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks @chuni. Thing is I do have the matches. It's not that I am failing to get a match. I am indeed getting the matching rows, but just one value, which is not even a key, is appearing as "NULL", yet all the other values in its row are ok. 

Let me check out that link on inner joins and see if it will help.

Comment: could you write the values of the tables separated for that row like:
the values of the row....
and the values of the row is making a join with

Comment: ok now i must leave , but check this out i'm sure here is the solution
try the example and you will understand
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp